# Как цифрам присвоить свой стиль?

Tags: php, html, css

Есть код
вывода цифр. Как сделать, чтобы можно было стиль прописать для каждой отдельной цифры. Допустим сегодня у меня высвечивается число 724. Так вот нужно чтобы подложка у 7, 2 и 4 была своя собственная. За решение заранее спасибо.

```
<style>.tablo{background:url("/image/tablo3.jpg") repeat scroll 50% 50%;
height: 230px;
width: 50px;
display: inline-block;
font-size: 310px;
color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
line-height: -moz-block-height;}</style>


<?php $nextWeek = (floor( time() / 86400) - 16375) * 1 + 100;?> <div class="tablo"><?php echo  $nextWeek; ?></div>
```

Или вот так проще вручную?

```
<style>.tablo{background:url("/image/1tablo.jpg") repeat scroll 50% 50%;
</style>
<div class="tabl">
<div class="tablo">1</div><div class="tablo">2</div><div class="tablo">4</div></div>
```

Comment: Переведите число в строку и работайте со элементом строки как с элементом массива... `$test = strval((floor( time() / 86400) - 16375) * 1 + 100);
echo $test[0]; echo $test[1]; echo $test[2]; `

Comment: Спасибо, добавьте ответом я его приму.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно преобразовать число к строке.

Т.к. по сути строка - это массив элементов типа `char`, то со строкой можно работать как с массивом, т.е. извлекая нужное значение по индексу.

```
<?php
    $nextWeek = strval((floor( time() / 86400) - 16375) * 1 + 100);
?>

<div class="tabl">
  <div class="tablo"><?= $nextWeek[0]; ?></div>
  <div class="tablo"><?= $nextWeek[1]; ?></div>
  <div class="tablo"><?= $nextWeek[2]; ?></div>
</div>
```